# lazyloading - повторный вывод элементов

Tags: php, jquery

Делал `infinite scroll` по вот этой [статье](http://www.w3bees.com/2013/09/jquery-infinite-scroll-with-php-mysql.html), только использовал mysqli вместо mysql.

Вот что получилось:

```
<?php
$page = (int) (!isset($_GET['p'])) ? 1 : $_GET['p'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookings ORDER BY id DESC";
$start = ($page * $limit) - $limit;

if( mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) > ($page * $limit) ){
$next = ++$page;
}
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql . " LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) < 1) {
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
echo 'Page not found!';
exit();
} ?>

    <tbody class="wrap">
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)): ?>
    <tr class="item" id="item-<?php echo $row['id']?>">
    <td><?php echo $row['uuid']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['surname']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['entry_date']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['exit_date']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['price']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['phone']?></td>
    <td>!</td>
    <td>!</td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile?>
    <?php if (isset($next)): ?>
    <div class="nav">
    <a href='booking.php?page=list&p=<?php echo $next?>'>Next</a>
    </div>
    <?php endif?>
    </tbody>
```

Но загрузка не кончается, подгружаются повторные записи в непонятном порядке.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем я ошибся.

Comment: а при чём тут lazyloading?

Comment: Не вижу объявления `$limit `

Comment: Возможно я ошибся с названием lazyloading. Да, $limit я забыл указать в вопросе. В коде она ест